# What is the correct HTTP code to indicate "not logged in"?

Tags: http, authentication, authorization, http-response-codes

If someone tries to visit an internal page which is only accessible once they have logged in, what error code should be returned? 403 doesn't seem right, because they have not authenticated. However, 401 doesn't work either, because that implies they can log in using basic auth, which we are not using.

Is it correct, when authentication is done via a method other than WWW-Authenticate headers, to use 403 in place of 401? If not, what code should be used?

Note: I have found some similar questions to this, but they all seem to be asking about sites using http basic auth, rather than any other authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

The status code 401 does not imply you support basic authentication. It means that the server would not serve the request because appropriate credentials were missing.

The server can send back a WWW-Authenticate header to indicate what types of credentials it supports. If you only support JWT tokens for example, you would send back 'bearer'.

Comment: My understanding was that WWW-Authenticate header is only able to indicate a limited range of values, are you saying that there is something I can set in the WWW-Authenticate so that I can use 401, but it won't ask the user to do a basic login?

Comment: Yes, if you do not support basic authN, don't send it back as an accepted scheme. See also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3

Comment: Thanks, I tried reading the rfc, but I still get the impression that it is not designed to allow a 401 response from a server that does not support basic auth. Can you direct me to somewhere that explains more clearly how to use it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. At the end of page 8, there's an example of what the server should return on an unauthenticated request.